# Unable to run Jasmine tests through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, google-chrome, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, karma-jasmine

I've Jasmine tests which are targeted to run on Chrome with following command -

```
karma start --specFileRegistry="DiagramComponent/test/DiagramComponent.specConfig.js" --outputFile="test-reports/test-case-report/NodeMappingCanvas.html"
```

This successfully run tests when I run from terminal on Linux machine but when run through Jenkins pipeline results into error -

```
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
     [exec]     Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"
     [exec] [115058:115058:0911/171053.130462:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.
```

Please suggest how I can get rid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma is trying to open a Chrome window and since it's running on an operating system without a windowing environment (Jenkins) it cannot open a window.

You need to configure Karma to use a browser that doesn't run in a window. It's called a headless browser.

The most popular choice these days would be to use Headless Chrome.
[karma-chrome-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher) supports running Headless Chrome.

It should be sufficient to replace `browsers: ['Chrome']` with `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']` in your Karma config.

Comment: Thanks `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']` is what I was looking for!